# Find the solution set of $\lfloor{2x+3}\rfloor\leq8$ inequality.

Tags: inequality

The question is easy,

Find the solution set of $\lfloor{2x+3}\rfloor\leq8$ inequality.

$$\lfloor{2x+3}\rfloor\leq8$$
$$\lfloor2x\rfloor+3\leq8$$
$$\lfloor2x\rfloor\leq5$$
$$2x<6$$
$$x<3$$
$$(-\infty,3)$$

In this solution, I could not unserstand how $\lfloor2x\rfloor\leq5\Rightarrow2x<6$. Can you explain to me, please?

Edit: $2x\leq6$ changed to $2x<6$ with $x\leq3$ to $x<3$.

Comment: What definition are you using for $[ \cdot ]$? There are three different definitions I often see: greatest integer, least integer, and nearest integer.

Comment: It should be **greatest integer**. I am also editing the question. Thanks!

Comment: It might also be noteworthy that the solution is wrong: for example, take $x=-10$. Then $|2x+3| = |-19| = 19$ but $19$ is greater than $8$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I edited the question, you can look at it again.

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE Post an answer to my question. I will accept it, you have solved it. Also, sorry for misunderstand the correct typing of greatest integer with $[|.|]$ this showed in my textbook. We use this typing for it. But, I learned how to type it correct. Thanks for your helps! I'm waiting you to post an answer.

Comment: Not needed. You answered it to your own.

Comment: It is also useful to see that since $\lfloor x\rfloor=k$ on interval $[k,k+1)$ then $\lfloor nx\rfloor=k$ on interval $[k/n,(k+1)/n)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $\lfloor 2x\rfloor=5$ on interval $[5/2,3)$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I didn't understand the main idea of equation that you wrote. Could you tell me the explanation of the equation with words, please? Also if you can give some examples with some various values, it would make me happy! Thanks!

Comment: In my comment, I should have specified that $k$ is an integer and $n$ is a *positive* integer. For example, if you wish to solve $\lfloor 3x-7\rfloor\le-2$, you rewrite it as $\lfloor 3x\rfloor-7\le-2$ then $\lfloor 3x\rfloor\le5$. Then we conclude that $\lfloor 3x\rfloor=5$ for $x\in[5/3,6/3)=[5/3,2)$ so $x<2$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Oh, wow! I understood. It gives in which range of numbers' greatest integer value will 5. This is very useful! Have a good day, sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** that 
$$2x= \lfloor 2x \rfloor + \{ 2x \} < \lfloor 2x \rfloor +1 \leq 5+1=6$$

since the fractional part $\{ 2x \} \in [0,1)$.

Comment: This looks like, the best equation to show relations between things. Can you explain the equation with words, please? I can't understand the meaning of it. Also, $\{.\}$ or $\{2x\}$ stands for what?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\lfloor2x\rfloor\leq5\Rightarrow2x<6$$ Not $$\lfloor2x\rfloor\leq5\Rightarrow2x\le6$$

because  $$2x=6\implies \lfloor 2x \rfloor =6$$

Therefore you have $$2x<6$$ which implies $$x<3$$

Comment: Could you please explain  $2x=6\implies \lfloor 2x \rfloor =6$? I guess the right-hand-side needs to stay as 5. An example would help. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with @NoChange. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the floor of an integer is the same as that integer. Therefore if $2x=6$ which is an integer we get $\lfloor 2x \rfloor =6$

Comment: True, but the question is not about integers only, as far as I can tell. I see that x has to be <= 2.5.

Comment: Oh, I see. @MohammedRiazi-Kermani means, I have wrong in the question. I'm editing it now. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani I will give you positive vote when I got 15 reputations.

Comment: Thanks for your attention